# Which function can adding product tax price

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tax

I need do some calculation , so i need know the file name and path for.

```
Product tax price adding to product price.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need to find the caluclation of tax .

```
app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Helper\Data.php
```

Find Protected **function _calculatePrice**. This is the file and function for tax calculation.